# Are any of the expansions "official"

Tags: total-annihilation

I just purchased Total Annihilation (with the two expansion packs), and when I was looking at [tauniverse.com](http://www.tauniverse.com/), and saw a bunch of "packs", such as "The Crusader's Unit Pack", as well as numerous "bugfix" patches. Are any of these "official releases", or are they third-party mods?

Comment: They're all third party mods.

Comment: the Bugfixes too?

Comment: They're under the Mod category.  I'd call that unofficial.  They seem to be pretty careful about ensuring things aren't tagged with official, ie. by the, or sanctioned by, the devs.  There's even an unofficial patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only official expansion packs are *Core Contingency* and *Battle Tactics*, as per the [Total Annihilation Commander Pack GOG.com page.](http://www.gog.com/gamecard/total_anihilation_commander_pack)

The rest are unofficial (community-made) mods or bug fixes.